# Calling a code from one dispatch queue to run in another

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, core-bluetooth

I am running a CBPeripheralManager on a global dispatch queue with high priority (it's one of the initialization options). From that queue I create a dispatch timer to perform a repeated task on a custom serial queue. When that repeated task finishes, I call a member function from a dispatch_async block who specifies the global queue again.

To sum up, I'm trying to field callbacks to delegate functions on the global dispatch queue. Then calling a repeated, timed task within a custom serial queue. Finally, I want to call a function from within the serial queue to run back on the global queue.

Is that final function running outside of the serial queue, in the global queue? The dispatch_asyn for the global queue is contained within the serial queue block.

Comment: Can you show at least some pseudo-code so that the structure of all this becomes a little easier to visualize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is like the following, right?

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH
let globalQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)
dispatch_async(globalQueue) {

    // 
    // This block is invoked on globalQueue
    // do CBPeripheralManager task
    //

    let serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("custom", nil)
    let timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, serialQueue)
    // set timer
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer) {

        //
        // This block is invoked on serialQueue
        // do task
        // 

        if finishedRepeatedTasks {
            dispatch_async(globalQueue) {

                // (A)
                // This block is invoked on globalQueue
                // call a member function
                //
            }
        }
    }
    dispatch_resume(timer)

}
```

And you mean `(A)` block `call a member function` was invoked on Global Queue?

Yes.

Comment: Yes, that is the gist of it. I run `init(delegate:queue:options:)` using the global queue, and I'm assuming that means the callbacks are called on the global queue. If my assumption is correct, then the above code simulates the code just fine.

Comment: Eh, then, this is an answer, right? Why don't you accept this answer?

Comment: Didn't realize you had written 'Yes'. Accepted.